# How to Iterate over grouped items and compare them?

Tags: c#, group-by, linq-to-objects

I'm having a hard time with this approach since I am new to Entity Framework. I actually don't know if there is something special related to EF or if the limitation is on me.

I would like to group some records from my database and after that, I'd like to iterate over the groups, then iterate over the elements on each group comparing it with all the other elements in the same group.

I have created two simple classes to illustrate the scenario:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClass { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

What I have so far with a context injected is:

```
this.MyContext.MyClass
            .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToList() // need to materialize here
            .ForEach(grp =>
            {
                // compare each item with all the other
                // items in the current group        
            });
```

But I don't know how to iterate over the items and then compare with the others in the same group.

Comment: I have tried two nested `Foreach` statements but I have never faced this kind of situation and never imagined three nested `foreach` statements could do something performatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code, the quesiton becomes what type is `grp`?

```
this.MyContext.MyClass
  .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
  .ToList() // need to materialize here
  .ForEach(grp =>
  {
    // compare each item with all the other
    // items in the current group        
  });
```

Well the `grp` variable is of type [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx). That type derives from `IEnumerable<TElement>` so each `grp` is a *list* of `TElement` so you can `foreach` or do whatever you want to all the items in the grp.

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v5Bq7k).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I should make three nested foreach statements? This just bugged my mind but thanks I will try that.

Comment: Thank you so much I got everything working with the Fiddle Example you provided. In my case I had to compare every person with each other in the same group so I just added another nested loop. Thank you again.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `grp` is an `IGrouping<int, MyClass>`. You can treat it as an `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. For instance, you can get the item with the biggest Id like this:

```
this.MyContext.MyClass
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToList() // need to materialize here
    .ForEach(grp =>
    {
         MyClass itemWithMaxId = grp.FirstOrDefault();
         foreach (MyClass item in grp)
         {
             if (item.Id > itemWithMaxId.Id)
             {
                 itemWithMaxId = item;
             }
         }      
    });
```

Note, however, that the `ForEach` method does not return anything, it only performs the specified action on each element of the list. If you want to get something, for instance the item with the biggest Id of each group, I suggest you to use the `Select` method provided by `Linq`, like in this example:

```
var itemsWithMaxIdByGroup = this.MyContext.MyClass
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToList() // need to materialize here
    .Select(grp =>
    {
         MyClass itemWithMaxId = grp.First();
         foreach (MyClass item in grp.Skip(1))
         {
             if (item.Id > itemWithMaxId.Id)
             {
                 itemWithMaxId = item;
             }
         }  

         return itemWithMaxId;    
    });
```

Comment: Groups generated by GroupBy will always have at least one element. In other words, they'll never be empty

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You are right, I fixed that in my example, thanks.